# Schengen visa extension more than 90 days

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-extensions

My spouse works in Germany with work permit and as a resident permit . due to the duration of his work permit I didn't get my dependent visa . if I apply for visitors visa for 90 days is it possible to extend it ? Because my kid really miss him a lot . she used to search for him daily . she is 1.5 years old .

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately for you the Schengen 90/180 rule is hard and fast.  The only way to go to the Schengen area for more than 90 days is to get a national visa from the country where you will reside.  As you were not granted a dependent visa for Germany, you cannot exceed the 90/180 rule.

With a multiple-entry visitors visa, however, you can spread your 90 days out, so you could for example visit for one or two weeks every month (if you can afford the air fare).  Another option would be to seek a national visa from Germany or a neighboring country in  your own right, but this might prove difficult while you are raising a toddler.  Questions about that would be off topic here, but you can ask them at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).